# How to return value of mouse position after event

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

It gets your mouse position after clicks, but I can't return the X and Y value to use in other functions. Such as the codes below, it prints at the first time, but do nothing with the second print. I think x0, y0 are not returned and they are still local variables.

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
w = Canvas(root, width=1000, height=640)
w.pack()
def getorigin(eventorigin):
    global x0, y0
    x0 = eventorigin.x
    y0 = eventorigin.y
    print(x0, y0)
    return x0, y0
w.bind("<Button 1>",getorigin)
print(x0, y0)
```

Comment: you can't `return`. You have to assign to global variables and later use in other funciton or directly run function which needs this values. In current code you don't use it in other function. `print()` outside function is executed even before you see window because `mainloop()` starts all and it shows window.

Comment: your code works correctly for me if I add `x0=0, y0=0` outside function to correctly execute `print()` which is outside function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't return from function assigned to event (or used in `command=`, `bind()` or `after()`). You can only assign to global variable and later use in other function.

Your `print()` after `bind()` is executed before `mainloop()` shows window and it is NOT "other function".

I use two functions: one to get values when left mouse button is pressed, and second to use these values when right mouse button is pressed. Second function uses values from first function. It shows that value from first function are assigned to global variables.

```
from tkinter import *

# --- functions ---

def getorigin(event):
    global x0, y0 # inform function to assing to global variables instead of local variables

    x0 = event.x
    y0 = event.y

    print('getorigin:', x0, y0)

def other_function(event):
    #global x0, y0 # this function doesn't assign to variables so it doesn't need `global`
    print('other function', x0, y0)

# --- main ---

# create global variables 
x0 = 0  
y0 = 0

root = Tk()

w = Canvas(root, width=1000, height=640)
w.pack()

w.bind("<Button-1>", getorigin)
w.bind("<Button-3>", other_function)

print('before mainloop:', x0, y0) # executed before mainloop shows window

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: if I want to take the x0,y0 numbers from getorigin and use them in other_function, what should I do?

Comment: you have all in code. `getorigin` assigns values to global `x0`, `y0` (it is not local variables) and `other_function` uses this global values. You don't have to do anything more. See on text printed in console when you run it. If you click left button then it shows `getorigin` with some values `x0`, `y0`. When you click right button then it shows the same values as in `getorigin` (not `0,0`) because 'other function'  get values from the same global variables `x0`, `y0`

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Hi, if I want the first left click to get getorigin, another left click to do other_function, what should I do?

Comment: Assign to `<Button-1>` function which counts clicks (using global variable ie. `count`) and this function has to also do: if `count == 1` then it executes `getorigin()`, if `count == 2` then it executes `other_function()`